# Insertion sort basic operation count

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I have an assignment that compares between insertion and merge sort using empirical analysis of algorithms,and I'm using basic operation count for measuring the efficiency.
My question: is it normal for the operation count to be the same every time for the same input size? (knowing that I'm generating random values so the values are different for every run)

This is my method (In java):

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] randomArray) {
    int key, j;
    for (int i = 1; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
        key = randomArray[i];
        j = i - 1;
        increasCounter();
        while (j >= 0 && randomArray[j] > key) {
            randomArray[j + 1] = randomArray[j];
            j--;
        }
        randomArray[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

where the basic operation is the comparison "randomArray[j] > key"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should increase the counter only too inside this code

```
while (j >= 0 && randomArray[j] > key) {
        increaseCounter();
        randomArray[j + 1] = randomArray[j];
        j--;
    }
```

we count the efficiency you need to count number of steps that program execute before finish, the code before only count how many times it loops inside the for code it doesn't count the loop inside the while one and it make it only count the number of array

Comment: Welcome to SO. I feel your answer is correct, but it would be more helpful to the OP if you explained why they should move the `increaseCounter` call inside the while loop (keying in on the OPs statement of `where the basic operation is the comparison "randomArray[j] > key"`)

Comment: thank you for your advice well i think it's because when we count the efficiency you need to count number of steps that program execute before finish, the code before only count how many times it loops inside the for code it doesn't count the loop inside the while one and it make it only count the number of array

Comment: You are correct. My suggestion is for you to edit your answer to include that information.  It is helpful for the OP and for future question searchers to not just see code and a "do this" type of statement, but rather for them to see the code and a brief explanation of why it would help/work/solve the problem.